# Delete duplicate rows in mysql, keep XX rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to keep the 10 latest duplicate rows and delete all the others.

I'm using the below code, but it deletes all the records except for one.

```
DELETE FROM `history` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MIN(n.id) FROM history n GROUP BY n.url) x)`
```

Comment: Consider providing DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: Try to select all duplicate rows then delete this rows and make a insert afterwards. And why do you need 10 duplicate rows? ;)

Comment: `SELECT MIN(n.id) FROM history` only returns one row

Comment: Why would you expect this to keep 10 rows?

Comment: Perhaps you could start with *"How can I retrieve the first 10 records per group"*. There's plenty of info on SO on that topic, so take a look around.

Comment: actually every record has unique content, there only duplicate is URL, so i want to display latest content on webpage, so i don't need others.so i want find duplicates and remove them if found more than 10

Comment: You probably also want to keep the 10 most recent ones. For us to figure out a prober SQL command we need some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

This code will remove all duplicate row who have more then 10 duplicates.

```
DELETE FROM `history` WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT MIN(n.id) FROM history n GROUP BY n.url having count(n.url) > 10
    ) x 
)
```

Comment: this code delete all rows and keep one. not meet my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that will work.

```
DELETE
FROM
  history
WHERE
  id NOT IN
  (SELECT
    id 
   FROM
     (
      SELECT
        @num:=IF(@current=url, @num+1, 1) AS row_num, 
        @current:=url AS group_url, 
        id
      FROM
        history
      ORDER BY
        id
     ) AS `internal`
   WHERE
     row_num<=15
  )
```

Comment: this code wont work in PHP. if i am not wrong @num:= is not work with php.

Comment: you have put just "[Query]" and then run in mysql_query($query) what will defiantly work.

Comment: its not return stable result for every URL. Some time its keep 10 some time 4 and some time delete all. Its change keeping value on duplicate values. if we have 39 duplicates it will keep 30 records. it must keep at least 9 10 or 11 records with any bigger values of duplicates.